# C# - Dependency Injection of ILogger When Testing

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am learning C# with .Net-Core. I am new to dependecy injection. I am trying to understand how to inject `ILogger<T>` when testing a class library used within a Blazor Web App.

I have created a *MotionDetectionConverter* class that injects `ILogger<T>` in constructor.

Within the *Read* method of that class I instantiate another helper class *JsonVisitor*. If I want to add logging ability to *JsonVisitor* class I can add an `ILogger<JsonVisitor>` parameter to the constructor. However, I do not understand how to get this injected? Should the *MotionDetectionConverter* *Read* method do the dependency inection? How would this be done for testing?

**MotionDetectionConverter class**

```
    internal sealed class MotionDetectionConverter : JsonConverter<MotionDetection>
    {
        private readonly ILogger _log;

        public MotionDetectionConverter(ILogger<MotionDetectionConverter> logger)
        {
            _log = logger;
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
        {
            _log.LogInformation("CanConvert {} => {}", typeToConvert.ToString(), (typeToConvert == typeof(MotionDetection)));
            return (typeToConvert == typeof(MotionDetection));
        }

        public override MotionDetection Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            JsonVisitor visitor = new JsonVisitor(ref reader, options);

            Detection details = new Detection();
            details.accept(visitor);

            return details.ToModel();
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MotionDetection motionDetection, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
                throw new NotImplementedException("Serialization of MotionDetection objects is not implemented");
    }
```

**JsonVisitor Class**

```
internal ref struct JsonVisitor
    {
        // private ILogger _log;
        private Utf8JsonReader _reader;
        private JsonSerializerOptions _options;

        #region Constructor

        public JsonVisitor(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, JsonSerializerOptions options) // ILogger<JsonVisitor> log)
        {
            // _log = log;
            _reader = reader;
            _options = options;
        }
        #endregion

        public void DeserializeMotionInfo(Details target)
        {
            if (_reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
                throw new NotSupportedException();

            target.plug = JSON.ReadStringProperty(ref _reader, MotionInfoPropertyNames.Plug);
            target.name = JSON.ReadStringProperty(ref _reader, MotionInfoPropertyNames.Name);
            target.reason = JSON.ReadStringProperty(ref _reader, MotionInfoPropertyNames.Reason);
            target.img = JSON.ReadStringProperty(ref _reader, MotionInfoPropertyNames.Img);
            target.imgHeight = JSON.ReadIntProperty(ref _reader, MotionInfoPropertyNames.ImgHeight);
            target.imgWidth = JSON.ReadIntProperty(ref _reader, MotionInfoPropertyNames.ImgWidth);
            target.time = JSON.ReadDateTimeOffsetProperty(ref _reader, MotionInfoPropertyNames.Time);

            _reader.Read();
            if (_reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndObject)
                throw new JsonException();

            // _log.LogInformation(string.Format("Completed Read operation for MotionInfo object, token type is now => {0}", reader.TokenType));
        }
}
```

Comment: You should inject `MotionDetectionConverter` as another dependency to `JsonVisitor`, which in turn takes all its dependencies with it. Then you just use it normally and when you need the `MotionDetectionConverter` just use it like any other injected variable, like you're doing with `Utf8JsonReader`.

Comment: @Alejandro ```JsonVisitor``` is used by the ```Read``` method of ```MotionDetectionConverter```. The ```MotionDetectionConverter``` is a ```System.Text.Json.JsonConverter``` It uses ```Utf8JsonReader``` as a ref struct that is supplied when the ```Read``` method is triggered during deserialization. Not sure how ```JsonVisitor``` can be injected into constructor due to this dependency on ```Utf8JsonReader``` in the ```Read``` method.